# Allow shell access for key holders OR password login for whitelisted IP addresses

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, openssh

As a first line of defense against brute-force attacks, I've restricted SSH login attempts with TCP wrappers (denying access by default, and maintaining an IP whitelist in `/etc/hosts.allow`).

However, I sometimes need to access my server from an IP address that's not in the whitelist (and my system ends up blocking my own attempts).

Is it possible to permit SSH keyed logins for all IP addresses, but prohibit password-only logins from IP's not in a given whitelist? I know I can configure SSH to only allowed keyed logins, but I'd like to keep the ability to log in with a password on a range of IP addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PasswordAuthentication no

Match Address 192.168.1.0/24
    PasswordAuthentication yes

Match Address 2001:470:1f0b:915::/64
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I also set different banner files using `Banner` to make it clear when password logins are accepted.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. To future viewers, just to be clear, this belongs in `sshd_config`.

Comment: And what if I do not have an `sshd_config`? I'm using fail2ban but want to set it up for whitelisting. Guess I ought to make a new question

Comment: @Jonathan: I'm quite sure you have a `sshd_config` if you use OpenSSH. And yeah, if you're asking about fail2ban, it has _absolutely nothing_ to do with this question.